# Is there any authoritative source where I can find a list of companies producing Sustainable Aviation Fuel in the U.S?

Tags: commercial-aviation, fuel, fuel-systems

Is there any authoritative source (website, directories, etc.) where I can find a list of companies producing Sustainable Aviation Fuel (SAF) in the U.S?

Based on media reports it seems that there are close to 50 companies currently that are producing SAF in the U.S, however after extensive research I could find a list of 10 companies only.

I could find quite a few such companies operating in Europe. Some of them have operations in the US. However, couldn't find any source that states how many such companies operate in the U.S
[image]

Will appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: What media reports indicate 50 sources? Where did you find a list of 10?

Comment: @tedder42 Various magazines that focuses on green fuel, occassionally a few TV stations. They suggest that there are close to 50 such companies in the US, but does not mention all the companies. So I went through several of these magazines, websites and so far found the names of 10 companies.

Comment: There may be 50 companies *researching* sustainable aviation fuels, but I'd be surprised if there were even 10 *producing* them.

Comment: @RonBeyer There are more than 10 companies producing various types of SAF here in Europe itself. I have added an image to illustrate that. Highly unlikely that the corresponding figure for the US will be drastically low, especially given the recent focus on SAF.